# merging two git repositories, one a git-cvs clone, one git-svn clone

Tags: svn, git, cvs, transition

I am using code from a CVS controlled repository (@sourceforge). Instead of using it directly, I was using a git clone of it made by someone else. In my clone I have several modifications.

In the meantime the upstream project has switched to SVN (@googlecode). I was able to create an automatically updated git clone of that myself.

Now I would like to apply my previous modifications of the CVS/git into the SVN/git. The SHA's are unfortunately different for the same commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your patches are in a single linear sequence, you can do this pretty easily using ["git format-patch"](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) and ["git am"](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html).  First switch the new repository to the revision from which your changes should sprout and create a new branch to hold your changes:

```
cd $NEWREPO
git checkout -b my-changes $SPROUT_POINT
```

Then use "git format-patch" to export the range R1..R2 of commits that you want to migrate and "git am" to apply them in the new repository:

```
(cd $OLDREPO; git format-patch -k --stdout R1..R2) | (cd $NEWREPO; git am -k)
```

I recommend first applying the patches to the revision corresponding to the CVS revision from which they originally sprouted, as this should succeed without any conflicts.  Then, if necessary, use ["git rebase"](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) within the new repository to move the commits to the tip of the appropriate Subversion branch.

Comment: should be 'git checkout -b my-changes $SPROUT_POINT' instead of 'git co ...'

Comment: Thanks; changed.  I guess not everybody uses the same aliases as I do :-)

Answer (score 0):

Other option is pulling the changes from your CVS repo and rebasing them on SVN repo. Like this (everything done in svn repo)

```
git remote add cvs-repo /path/to/you/cvs/clone
git fetch cvs-repo
git checkout -b my-branch-with-changes cvs-repo/my-branch-with-changes
git rebase --onto ${SVN_UPSTREAM} ${CVS_UPSTREAM}
```

The last `git rebase` should take all your commits based on cvs-upstream, and "connect them" to your last SVN ones.

In graphics:

```
cvs-repo: A -- B -- C -- D (last_cvs_commit) -- E -- F (your changes)

svn-repo: G -- H -- I -- J (last_svn_commit)
```

(where A--B--C--D are identical to G--H--I--J, and just have different hashes

you check out branch with your changes and run:

```
git rebase --onto J D
```

which changes the situation to:

```
svn-repo: G -- H -- I -- J (last_svn_commit) -- E' -- F' (your changes, rebased)
```

Comment: Thanks. This might work as well, Haven't tested it as the earlier method worked for me.